# How do I fix this code so that it will print 3 times for sure

Tags: java, arrays

Sorry for bad title because I have no idea what should the title be for this question

look at my complicated code:

```
`class diverfuckyou{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    int[] array = new int[5];
    int[] first = new int[2];
    int[] last = new int[2];
    boolean check;
    boolean check2;
    for(int a = 0; a < 3 ; a++)
    {
      //
      check2 = false;
      for(int j = 0; j <array.length ; j++)
      {

        do
        {
          check = false;
          int random = (int)(Math.random() * 5  + 1);
          array[j] = random;
          if ( j > 0 )
          {// check if it is duplicate in single time
            for( int i = 0; i < j  ; i++)
            {        
              if (array[j] == array[i])
              {
                check = true;
              }  
            }
          }
          if ( j == 0 )
          {
            for(int n = 0 ; n < a ;n++)
            {
              if ( first[n] == array[j])
              {
                check = true;
              }
            }
          }

          if ( j == 4)
          {
            for(int n = 0 ; n < a ;n++)
            {
              if ( last[n] == array[j])
              {
                check = true;
              }               
            }
          }

        }while(check);
      }



      if ( a  < 2 )
      {
        first[a] = array[0];
        last[a] = array[array.length-1];

      }
      for(int j = 0; j <array.length ; j++)
      {
        System.out.println(array[j]); 
      }
      System.out.println();

    }   
  }
} '
```

First this code will randomly choose number between 1 and 5 with no duplicate and it will do it for 3 times and each time the first number and last number will be different.

here is the problem, instead of using word to describe my problem i will use an example:

let say on the first time I got:

1
2
3
4
5

Therefore, the second time, I cannot have 1 as my first number and 5 as my last number.

2
3
5
4
1

Now, on the third time, I cannot have 1 and 2 as my first number because 1 and 2 was the first number on the first time and second time.I cannot have 1 and 5 as my last number because 1 and 5 was the last last number on the first time and second time. There is a problem :

3
1
2
4
??

The last number will not be any number because 5 is the only one left for the last number, but the last number cannot be 5 so the do-while loop will keep running. Therefore, it never print the numbers.

You can copy my code and run it for 3 times and you will know i meant

Please feel free to ask any question if you don't understand what i want to do and i will try to answer your question :). ALso sorry for bad english.

Comment: Could you rename the class to something nicer ?

Answer (score 0):

This should work.  It keeps track of numbers used in the first and last positions in the array `used`. `used[FIRST_PLACE][x]` is true if the number `x` has been used in the first position, and `used[LAST_PLACE][x]` is true if the number x has been used in the last position.

Within the for loop, the one-dimensional array `alreadyUsedInRow` keeps track of which numbers have been used in the current row. `alreadyUsedInRow[x]` is true if the number `x` has already been used in the current row.

In each row, the algorithm first chooses the first and last numbers, because they have the most constraints on their choice.  Then the 2nd, 3rd and 4th numbers are chosen.

```
import java.util.Random;
public class Rand15 {

    public static final int FIRST_PLACE = 0;
    public static final int LAST_PLACE = 1;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Random r = new Random();

        boolean [][] used = new boolean [2][5];

        // Do this three times
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {

            // Keep track of numbers used in current iteration
            boolean [] alreadyUsedInRow = new boolean [5];
            int [] candidate = new int [5];

            // Get the first place          
            candidate[0] = r.nextInt(5);

            // If this number has been already used in first place
            while (used[FIRST_PLACE][candidate[0]]) {
                // Get another number
                candidate[0] = r.nextInt(5);
            }
            // Set first place used to true for this number
            used[FIRST_PLACE][candidate[0]] = true;
            // This number has already been used for current row
            alreadyUsedInRow[candidate[0]] = true;


            // Get last place for this row
            candidate[4] = r.nextInt(5);

            // If this number hasalready been used in last place try again
            while (used[LAST_PLACE][candidate[4]] || alreadyUsedInRow[candidate[4]] ) {
                candidate[4] = r.nextInt(5);

            }
            used[LAST_PLACE][candidate[4]] = true;
            alreadyUsedInRow[candidate[4]] = true;

            // Get 2nd place
            candidate[1] = r.nextInt(5);
            while (alreadyUsedInRow[candidate[1]]) {
                candidate[1] = r.nextInt(5);
            }
            alreadyUsedInRow[candidate[1]] = true;

            // Get 3rd place
            candidate[2] = r.nextInt(5);
            while (alreadyUsedInRow[candidate[2]]) {
                candidate[2] = r.nextInt(5);
            }
            alreadyUsedInRow[candidate[2]] = true;

            // Get 4th place
            candidate[3] = r.nextInt(5);
            while (alreadyUsedInRow[candidate[3]]) {
                candidate[3] = r.nextInt(5);
            }
            alreadyUsedInRow[candidate[3]] = true;

            System.out.print(candidate[0]+1);
            System.out.print(candidate[1]+1);
            System.out.print(candidate[2]+1);
            System.out.print(candidate[3]+1);
            System.out.println(candidate[4]+1);
        }
    }

}
```

Sample output from 3 runs:

```
45123
51432
13425

13245
45123
34152

24531
52134
15243
```

Comment: There's also a way in which you can prevent the repeated calls to r.nextInt().  You start off using `rand.nextInt(5)`, then `rand.nextInt(4)` and so on.  Using this scheme, `rand.nextInt` isn't choosing the actual number, but number (e.g., 1st, 3rd) within the remaining choices to select.  So, to take the example of choosing a number within a row, suppose that `3` is already chosen, so the remaining numbers are 1245. Next, call `rand.nextInt(4)`. If this returns 3, then choose 5 (index 3 in the sequence 1245).

Comment: Is there any easier way?? becuase im a high school student and i haven't learn the code "used"

Comment: `used` is just an array of boolean values defined by the programmer, similar to your array named `array`.  There's nothing special or magical about it.  You are already using boolean variables (like `check` and `check2`) in your code so you know how they work.  If you don't like the name `used` you can rename the boolean array to anything you want.  Just note that there are actually two boolean arrays in the solution: one keeps track of which numbers have already been used in the current row, and another array that keeps track of which numbers have been used in the first and last positions.